# Ajax calling WebMethod nothing happens

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, webmethod

Why oh why doesn't this code do Anything?! What is wrong with my ajax?
My ajax:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/index.aspx/Uppdatera",
                data: "{ Id:"+ JSON.stringify($item.Id) +" }",
                error: 
                    alert("error")
            });
```

My C#:

```
 [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public static void Uppdatera(object id)
        {
            id.ToString();
            using (StreamWriter s = new StreamWriter("C:/Users/robert/Documents/visual studio 2013/Projects/GolvProjektet/GolvProjektet/hej.txt"))
            {
                s.Write("hej" + id);
            }
        }
```

Comment: you have to use Firebug and click on 'net' and read your ajax request and responses.

Comment: I am sure that something happens, have you debugged? Have you check in something like fiddler or browser dev tools to see what the request is doing?

Comment: What's it meant to do? We can't help if you don't explain what the desired behaviour is, what it's doing instead, and what you've already tried.

Comment: At the moment, I am just trying to make the WebMethod work, and after that I will work on what it will do :)
I am clicking a button, and then my ajax is running. But the file hej.txt is not created.

Comment: @prospector I get error code 301: Move Permanently.

Answer (score 0):

Add the contentType y dataType in ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "/index.aspx/Uppdatera",
                data: "{ Id:"+ JSON.stringify($item.Id) +" }",
                error: 
                    alert("error")
            });
```

Comment: Still no file is created.